# Inside a file there are a set of function calls and if conditions , how to parse them into c++ program as its own statements

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction

This is the content inside a text file which has function call and if conditions.
File is written by following python syntax.

***File.txt***

```
move(1,2,3)
stop(1,4,5)
if(condition):
   move(1,1,1)
   if(condition2):
      start(4,2,1)
   elif(condition3):
      stop(0,0,0)
elif(condition4):
   move(10,0,0)
```

*** *.cpp***

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

 ifstream myReadFile;
 myReadFile.open("file.txt");
 char output[100];
 if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
 while (!myReadFile.eof()) {


    myReadFile >> output;
    cout<<output;
/*
inside here how can i take content from file and interpret and run it as normal c++ commands
*/
 }
}
myReadFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Now, after reading the content using c++ ,how to parse it and run the following commands inside c++.

***I dont know the tags which i have given are correct, so do let me know proper tags***

Comment: You need a C++ compiler for that. Parsing C++ / writing a C++ *interpreter* is *not* a trivial task.

Comment: Writing a compiler/intepreter is a huge undertaking. I recommend you research the field, study up, and come back here after you've built your knowledge base up. There are a lot of tutorials and textbooks out there. Hit them first before you hit Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JohnKugelman could you suggest me some link and tutorials, as i new to this topic, if not its fine.

Comment: I taught myself from the classic [dragon book](https://smile.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=dragon+book+compilers&qid=1580734962&sr=8-2), AKA *Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools*.